# Python: Purpose of "nested" dictionaries?

Tags: python

I see this in sample code frequently:

```
# Our mock database.
users = {'foo@bar.tld': {'password': 'secret'}}
```

wondering why not just say

```
passwords = {"foo@bar.tld": "secret"}
```

Where is the benefit of such a nested structure?

Definitely there is a drawback: need to make sure to name the key "password" the same for each user I set up...

Comment: Where do yo see this? We need more information about your context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it is often the case that you need to have more entries in each level of the dictionary, for example

```
users = {'foo@bar.tld': {'password': 'secret',
                         'name': 'john smith',
                         'creation_date': '2017/09/06'},
         'baz@qux.tld': {'password': 'secret',
                         'name': 'someone else',
                         'creation_date': '2017/08/02'}}
```

This is similar to the structure of JSON where you can have arbitrarily nested items to represent a hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you have more users, and every user has a password, username, age, date of birth, photo, id...etc, then this would be very inefficient :

```
users = {'foo@bar.tld': 'secret,userName,15,pic.png...etc'} # you also need other users with properties
```

Then you are forced to use :

```
users = {
          'foo@bar.tld': 
                        {'password': 'secret',
                         'username': 'userName',
                         'age': 15,
                         'photo': 'pic.png'},#etc...
          'user@two.tld': { # same thing ... }
        }
```